# Applying CSS filter on only half of image

Tags: html, css

I have a overlying div on my image with `filter: grayscale(100%);` filling up `50%` of the containing div but the filter will not apply over my image.

However if I put the image inside my `filterBar` div it will only make the whole image greyscale. I need the image to be greyscaled in relation to the number rating.

Is this possible to do?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/qadEoL?editors=1100)

**HTML**

```
<div class="rating-wrapper-v2 bp-rating row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="filterBar"></div>
    <img src="https://www.baopals.com/catalog/view/theme/lexus_megashop/image/Baopals-Facebook.png" style="width: 100px;" alt="Baopals Rating" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <p>BAOPALS SCORE</p>
    <span>2.5</span>
    <span>/</span>
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rating-wrapper-v2{
  width:300px;
}
.filterBar{
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: filter can be applied to image only not just for div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grayscale filter can be only applied to img tags.
There are several ways to solve what you are looking for, this is one of them:

```css
.rating-wrapper-v2{
  width:300px;
  height: 100px;
}
.img-container {
  position: relative;
}
.img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.img-container .filtered-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-container img.filtered {
  top: -50px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.stars-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.st-bg {
  position:absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://www.baopals.com/catalog/view/theme/lexus_megashop/image/Baopals-Facebook.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.st {
  position:absolute;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://www.baopals.com/catalog/view/theme/lexus_megashop/image/Baopals-Facebook.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
.st-0-5 {
  width: 50px;
}
.st-1 {
  width: 100px;
}
.st-1-5 {
  width: 150px;
}
.st-2 {
  width: 200px;
}
.st-2-5 {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<div class="rating-wrapper-v2 bp-rating row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="filterBar"></div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://www.baopals.com/catalog/view/theme/lexus_megashop/image/Baopals-Facebook.png" style="width: 100px;" alt="Baopals Rating" />
      <div class="filtered-container">
        <img src="https://www.baopals.com/catalog/view/theme/lexus_megashop/image/Baopals-Facebook.png" style="width: 100px;" alt="Baopals Rating" class="filtered"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <p>BAOPALS SCORE</p>
    <span>2.5</span>
    <span>/</span>
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Update

This example demonstrates how to generated a "1-5 stars rating like" with gray background effect:

> Note - the CSS there is not complete, but I think the general idea is good enough and you can complete it without me :)

```css
.stars-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.st-bg {
  position:absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://www.baopals.com/catalog/view/theme/lexus_megashop/image/Baopals-Facebook.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.st {
  position:absolute;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://www.baopals.com/catalog/view/theme/lexus_megashop/image/Baopals-Facebook.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
.stars-container.st-0-5 .st{
  width: 50px;
}
.stars-container.st-1 .st{
  width: 100px;
}
.stars-container.st-1-5 .st{
  width: 150px;
}
.stars-container.st-2 .st{
  width: 200px;
}
.stars-container.st-2-5 .st{
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<div class="stars-container container">
  <div class="st-bg row"></div>
  <div class="st row"></div>
</div>
<div class="stars-container st-0-5 container">
  <div class="st-bg row"></div>
  <div class="st row"></div>
</div>
<div class="stars-container st-1-5 container">
  <div class="st-bg row"></div>
  <div class="st row"></div>
</div>
<div class="stars-container st-2 container">
  <div class="st-bg row"></div>
  <div class="st row"></div>
</div>
<div class="stars-container st-2-5 container">
  <div class="st-bg row"></div>
  <div class="st row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work well thanks for the answer, I'm going to have to rethink my process of accomplishing this for other percentages haha

Comment: You are welcome. This is more like a hack for this :) what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Basically the rating is 1-5 and i want the image to be greyscaled in a percentage based on that. I think what im going to end up doing is just making a sprite map and `if (rating = 1) {background-position...}` to the  img div if that makes since haha. Seems like the best way to go about it

Comment: @NooBskie, check the update on my answer, I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: Wow this is exactly how i was thinking haha. Thanks a lot for the help I'd upvote again if i could:p